# RewriteRules for Query Strings

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have the following urls:

```
site/DB/guest/picture/25-298.jpg?v=140913231208
site/DB/guest/picture/25.jpg?v=140913231208
site/DB/user/cover/27-40.jpg?v=160913051508
site/DB/user/cover/27.jpg?v=160913051508

site/JS/main.js?v=160913132025
site/JS/utils/admin.js?v=1602144214027
site/CSS/main.css?v=160913132038
```

I want to be able to load them by accessing urls below:

```
guest/picture/140913231208/25-298.jpg
guest/picture/140913231208/25.jpg
user/cover/160913051508/27-40.jpg
user/cover/160913051508/27.jpg

js/160913132025/main.js
js/utils/1602144214027/admin.js
css/160913132038/main.css
```

I've tried to Rewrite some Rules. But I always get the Not Found Error.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)/(.*).(.*)$ site/JS/$2.$3\?v=$1 [L]
```

Comment: what rules did you try, what threads are you referring to

Comment: I meant Questions, not Threads, edited!

Comment: You can play around with your rewrite rules on [this page](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: I've added the code I've tried.

Comment: The _replacement_ part is _not_ a regular expression, so “escaping” the dot there is wrong.

Comment: It's still not working :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^guest/picture/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /site/DB/guest/picture/$2?v=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/cover/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /site/DB/user/cover/$2?v=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^js/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.js$ /site/JS/$2.js?v=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^js/utils/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.js$ /site/JS/utils/$2.js?v=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^css/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.css$ /site/CSS/$2.css?v=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

```
RewriteRule ^(js|css)(/utils)?/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$1$2/$4?v=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Works great for me! Is there a way may be to split js and css in one RewriteRule?

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR try the edit above

Comment: Not working, probably because of case, CSS and JS are uppercase in real url.